# CRM 4 Add Picklist Value

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I would like to create a possible value for a specific picklist on CRM4.

I can see that the possible values are located in the stringmap table.  My question is about how to *properly* add another record.  The objecttypecode (10063) and attributename (assessmenttype) already exist - I simply need to add a new option to the picklist.

Of course, not wanting to void our support, I cannot just add the record to the table.

I have exported the xml configuration of this entity, and I can see the picklist values in this file under the "options" node of the picklist attribute node.  I have imported this customization but it clearly is not all that needs to be done - my new values are neither in the stringmap table or visible on the form.  what else needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the metadata web service to make these updates. Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904037.aspx for a walkthrough of how to create picklists. You'll also want to look at the [UpdateAttributeRequest class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156253.aspx).